# Json date format conversion

Tags: android, date, date-format, simpledateformat

My json string response date is in this format:

```
"due_date":"2011-11-23"
```

I want to know how can i convert this into a mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: did you try this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject("\"due_date\":\"2011-11-23\"");
        String str = json.get("due_date").toString();
        String format="yyyy-MM-dd";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date date = sdf.parse(str);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```